# Unable to access my API from this swift class with Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to access to the API I installed on my Mac. The API works fine at this address `https://localhost:5001/users/`, when I run with browser it loads everything, when I try to load it with this code:

```
class ConnectorManager: NSObject {
    open class MyServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager {
        open override func serverTrustPolicy(forHost host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
            return ServerTrustPolicy.disableEvaluation
        }
    }

    let sessionManager = SessionManager(delegate:SessionDelegate(), serverTrustPolicyManager:MyServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: [:]))

    func getAllUsers() {
        let userUrl = ConnectorStatics.URL_BASE + ConnectorStatics.URL_USR
        sessionManager.request(userUrl, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                if let data = response.result.value {
                    if (data as? [[String : AnyObject]]) != nil {
                        print("data_1: \(data)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Unable to connect")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode shows me this errors:

```
2019-06-03 17:41:13.427145+0200 MyApp[73332:3683174] Task <25D82DBB-4754-4E5F-8A90-690BD0994323>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:5001/users/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:5001/users/, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <25D82DBB-4754-4E5F-8A90-690BD0994323>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <25D82DBB-4754-4E5F-8A90-690BD0994323>.<1>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]
2019-06-03 17:41:13.429975+0200 MyApp[73332:3683156] Task <25D82DBB-4754-4E5F-8A90-690BD0994323>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
2019-06-03 17:41:13.431713+0200 MyApp[73332:3683154] Task <25D82DBB-4754-4E5F-8A90-690BD0994323>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

What's wrong with my class? Can anyone help me to fix it? Thank you

Comment: That will only work if your app is run in a simulator on the same Mac.

Comment: I'm running it on the simulator... First of all I need to use this connection by the simulator... If you had a solution to work with simulator and with the real device just write it... In other word, I will know what's wrong in this code and what's the right solution to use it

Comment: This will never work on a real device because `localhost` is always the machine running the app.

Comment: Ok there's a way to use Alamofire with simulator and with real device? If there's a solution can you post here? Thank you

Comment: The issue is NOT with Alamofire but with the usage of `localhost`. This code will work on simulator with localhost and will work on a device if you provide a real url. That's it.

Comment: @inokey but why when I run it on the simulator it shows me the errors I wrote? I'm not understanding what's wrong...

Comment: Are you sure it's `https`? Are you able to create `URL` object with provided string? Have you tried using IP address instead of "localhost"?

Comment: @inokey I tried right now and when I type on browser `http://127.0.0.1/users` it shows me the URL not found page just to know: `static let URL_BASE = "https://localhost:5001" static let URL_USR = "/users/"`

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same issue I will post the solution:

```
private static var Manager : Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        // Create the server trust policies
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "localhost:5001": .disableEvaluation
        ]
        // Create custom manager
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        let man = Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )

        man.delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { session, challenge in
            var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .performDefaultHandling
            var credential: URLCredential?

            if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
                disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential
                credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
            } else {
                if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
                    disposition = .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
                } else {
                    credential = man.session.configuration.urlCredentialStorage?.defaultCredential(for: challenge.protectionSpace)

                    if credential != nil {
                        disposition = .useCredential
                    }
                }
            }

            return (disposition, credential)
        }

        return man
    }()
```

Now with this snippet the app works fine

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. It is much better to explain what was wrong and what this answer changes.